# Unable to set the full screen for remote video view using TwilioVideo(iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, video, twilio

I am using Twilio for Video calling and its working fine but the only issue is unable to set the full screen for remote video. Its showing vertically full but not horizontally, after searching in Twilio video docs I found the below snippet apparently not working.

```
let videoConstraints = TVIVideoConstraints { (constraints) in
constraints.maxSize = TVIVideoConstraintsSize960x540;
constraints.minSize = TVIVideoConstraintsSize960x540;
constraints.maxFrameRate = TVIVideoConstraintsFrameRateNone;
constraints.minFrameRate = TVIVideoConstraintsFrameRateNone;

camera = TVICameraCapturer(source: .frontCamera, delegate: self)
    localVideoTrack = TVILocalVideoTrack.init(capturer: camera!,
                                              enabled: true,
                                              constraints: videoConstraints)
```

Its throwing the below exception, Help me in this

```
"Error: Failed to create a video track using the local camera."
```

Video call is for iPhone SE, 6, 6s, 7 form factors

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I just noticed that while [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/specifying-video-constraints) does tell you to implement the constraints via `TVILocalVideoTrack.init` the specific iOS documentation says [not to use the `init`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.3.0/docs/Classes/TVILocalVideoTrack.html#//api/name/init) method.

Have you tried [`trackWithCapturer:enabled:constraints`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.3.0/docs/Classes/TVILocalVideoTrack.html#//api/name/trackWithCapturer:enabled:constraints:) instead?

```
TVILocalVideoTrack.trackWithCapturer(camera!, enabled: true, constraints: videoConstraints)
```

Comment: Showing this error 'trackWithCapturer(_:enabled:constraints:)' is unavailable: use object construction 'TVILocalVideoTrack(capturer:enabled:constraints:)'

Comment: Apologies, I'm not as familiar with Swift as I could be and messed that up. I'm checking with the team now to see if there's a way to debug why your `videoConstraints` didn't work. I'll update my answer soon.